# SQS policy doesn't grant access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

I created an SQS with an SQS Policy granting access to iam_user_1

```
Resources:
  MyQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName:
        'Fn::Join': ['-', ["my-queue-prefix", {Ref: Stage}]]
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 60
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20

  QueuePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - {Ref: MyQueue}
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sqs:ReceiveMessage
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - '<account_1>'
            Resource: {Ref: MyQueue}
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: 'arn:aws:iam::<account_1>:user/iam_user_1'
```

With this queue policy, my user is still unable to access the queue - 403 access denied. I also tried changing the `principal` to

```
Principal:
   AWS:
      - 'arn:aws:iam::<account_1>:user/iam_user_1'
```

Is it possible to allow an iam user access to read an SQS, using just the sqs policy. Do i have to modify the iam user policy to grant access to the sqs?

Comment: Yes, the IAM User's policy must allow the user to access SQS.

Comment: I find that if i modify the iam policy to allow access to the sqs and i totally delete the sqs policy, then the user is still able to access the sqs. In that case, what is the purpose of the sqs policy? For external accounts?

Comment: The Queue Policy is typically used to grant access to an entity outside of the Account.